# DDD aggregate performance

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, ddd-service

I'm new to DDD. Now I've an aggregate `Team` and entities `TeamMember`:

```
class Team {
  members: Map<TeamMemberId, TeamMember>;

  add(member) {
    assert(!members.has(member.id), "Team Member is already exists");
    this.members.set(member.id, member);
  }
}
```

When I execute `AddTeamMemberCommand`, the repository will load the entire aggregate from `MongoDB`.
**when the team is large, this may seem unacceptable**.

I found the following from google and stackoverflow:

- Use Id references instead of entities
- Lazy load
- Redesign aggregation
- ....

**I'm not sure which solution is right for me, or is there a better, more generic solution for this scenario?** Is there a GitHub sample project i can look at?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure where you Imported the assert method from, but I'd be careful. Those are generally for tests, and are usually program crashers upon failure. In a test, this is what you want. In your program, not so much.

Comment: If it is the Core java version of the method, the opposite is true. Instead of throwing an unchecked exception, an unacceptable condition will throw no error at all. What you want is between the two. You want it to throw an exception that you can catch. Consider a try/ catch loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a better, more generic solution for this scenario?

For reads/queries, where you aren't going to be changing the aggregate at all, lazy loading is *fine*.  In the world of CQRS, we might even avoid loading the aggregate altogether, instead just fetching a read-only copy of the information that we need.

---

> An AGGREGATE is a cluster of associated objects that we treat as a unit for the purpose of data changes.

If we're trying to make a change to an aggregate, and are tempted to leave a bunch of unnecessary information unloaded, that *may* imply that our aggregate boundaries are in the wrong places, and that we should be re-designing our domain model so that the loaded information better fits with what we need.

For example, if you are trying to update just Bob, not the entire team, then that may be a hint that Bob isn't an entity inside of the Team aggregate, but is instead belongs in a different, smaller aggregate, which has some relationship with team.

Mauro Servienti's [talk on aggregate boundaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hev65ozmYPI) may be a good starting point.